# Which kind of bow fits my needs

Tags: equipment, archery

I'm an archery beginner and I'm a bit overstrained by the massive supply of different bows.

I'm 1,94m tall, want to use "intuitive shooting" (I hope this is the right term) and intermediated sporty.

Okay, what I've found out so far is, that a "recursive bow" is the most modern bow for this discipline. However, I'm a little bit afraid that this bow is already too modern for me. I really want to have a pretty basic experience. Is this possible with this kind of bow?

Example for this kind:

- [image: Recursive Bow]
- Size: 70"
- Pull weight: 32 lbs

Another example is such a "Manaubow" which raises the impression of being more traditional.

[image]

Okay, here are my questions. Which size and pull weight should a bow have for me? Are the 70" and 32 lbs ok? Is a "recursive bow" able to provide a basic traditional experience or would something like a "Manaubow" be the better choice?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend going to an achey club and asking to try some of their bows. At the very least, go to an archery shop to try before you buy.

Type: a recurve bow, also known as Olympic, is probably a bit more beginner friendly. It has a rest for the arrow to sit on; with a longbow the arrow rests on the bow hand and often the fletches hit the hand on the way past, sometimes injuring the hand. A recurve has more choice for expansion with the addition of a sight, a long rod and a clicker, but you can also shoot "barebow" without these gadgets, at which point the experience is much closer to longbow.

Size: depends on your height and draw length. I can't advise this over the Internet. Go to a club or shop and ask them for advice.

Draw Weight: this depends on your strength. You will need to try shooting with a variety of weights to see what is comfortable. If you're learning, you're likely to improve quite quickly and progress from a lighter draw weight to a heavier one over the first few months. This is why it can be useful to shoot with a club where you can borrow a range of bows while you're learning.

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is perfect but I just want to add something for the additional information.

As far as I concern, "intuitive shooting" also means "Instinctive Archery"
Just like football, the player kicks the ball to pass to another player. Actually, the player doesn't need to have a proper mechanism to aim to another player, but based on his experience the way he kicks actually goes to exactly as he intends to do.

In this case, you can use whatever bow including the modern compound bow (of course you need to take out the sight tool) BUT the best of course whether the longbow or recurve bow. Before the modern era, every archer did the instinctive archery.

For a taller person like you, based on what I talked with some senior archers, draw length is the real problem that you need to take into account. This is because sometimes we heard people said that arm span is the same as the height. Then some people can buy the bow via online based on the bow specs. But actually that is not true, you can read this [scientific research here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8793422).

All in all, the ultimate solution, you need to try yourself at the archery shop/club and get the best timing for yourself in term of draw length and also draw weight. You can [read here](https://themodernarcher.com/recurve-bow-guide/) to understand the basic thing about recurve bow and determine the length of the bow that suits you.